# Complexity of greedy algorithm for TSP

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, greedy, traveling-salesman

I have a complete graph G = (V, E), with n vertices. I want to create a path that starts from a vertices, passes through all other vertices exactly once and returns to the start (a.k.a. a Hamiltonian path) of minimum length.

Edit: This is the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP), which is NP-Hard. I want to find a demonstration for this approximation algorithm:

Greedy algorithm:

1. Sort list L of all edges
2. Create empty list I
3. for e in L:
   3.1 if I+e does not form a cycle, add e to I
4. return I

I used "+" to show the union between a list and a element

The time complexity for the standard greedy algorithm is O(n*log(n)), if step 3 does not take longer.

In this case, the internet says that the time complexity is O(n^2*log(n)), because the algorithm has to check if there is a cycle before adding any edge to the list and I don't know how to demonstrate this complexity.

In my implementation, I used a breath first search to determine the absence of cycles, but I  am not sure if there is a faster method that would give the complexity I am looking for.

Edit: the solution does not need to use BFS, I can alter my implementation at any time.

To be clear, I know that the complexity is O(n^2*log(n)), I just need to demonstrate it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand that Hamiltonian path is NP-complete, which means you can't solve it in polynomial time (as if you could solve np=p), and your solution won't give you the Hamiltonian path..

Comment: Poor turn of phrase. Hamiltonian path in a complete graph is obviously in P.

Comment: OP, doing a BFS over a complete graph n times is going to put you at cubic running time. You can use detect potential cycles with a disjoint-set data structure instead, the same as in Kruskal's algorithm.

Comment: The TSP is NP-Hard, I believe, but the greedy algorithm is not. This is an approximation algorithm. It does not provide the optimal path. I want to find the demonstration for the algorithm I have provided. @JackRaBeat

Comment: I do BFS only over graph formed by the list of edges I. This graph has a maximum of n edges and n vertices, it is not a complete graph, it is the path that I want to create from the complete graph. @DavidEisenstat

Comment: Worded that poorly. Yes, each BFS is linear-time, but you need Theta(n^2) of them.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you describe does not produce a TSP solution, but a minimum spanning tree; in fact it is [Kruskal's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm). The actual time complexity (assuming an efficient implementation) is `O(n log n)`. Checking for a cycle can be done simply by maintaining a disjoint set structure and checking whether the vertices of an edge are in the same connected component.

If, rather than just avoiding cycles, you also avoided adding any edge which would result in a vertex with degree > 2, you would end up with a Hamiltonian path (the one from the minimum spanning tree). The time complexity (again, assuming an efficient implementation) would be the same, dominated by the edge sort.